# Animation using Seaborn relplot and Celluloid

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation, seaborn

I have a problem using Seaborn relplot when trying to make an animation. I have recreated the issue I have using one of the datasets that comes with Seaborn, below.

I suspect it is something to do with the `plt.figure()` not being the same as the `sns.relplot`. Any ideas on how to make this work would be greatly received. Thanks.

```
%matplotlib inline
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from celluloid import Camera
from IPython.display import HTML
import ffmpeg

df = sns.load_dataset('car_crashes')

f = plt.figure(figsize=(3,3))
camera = Camera(f)

# This might seem a little bit unnecessary, but its emulating the way I am plotting my other data source:
for i in range(0, len(df), 10):
    g = sns.relplot(x='total', y='abbrev', hue='abbrev', data=df.iloc[i:i+10 , [0,7]])                                                                        
    plt.axis('off')
    plt.title(f'THIS IS THE TITLE OF {i}')
    plt.gca().set_aspect('equal')
    camera.snap()
    
animation = camera.animate()
HTML(animation.to_html5_video())
```

Comment: [`relplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.relplot.html) is a figure level function, and creates a new figure at each call. I think you can't force seaborn to draw such a plot on an existing figure.

Comment: If your `relplot` only consists of one subplot, you could try to directly call seaborn's `scatterplot` which accepts an `ax` parameter, for example `ax=plt.gca()`. In case you need multiple subplots, you could try to draw them one by one (`fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=..., ncols=...)` and then `sns.scatterplot(...., ax=axes[i,j]` in a loop).